# Laravel 5.2: TokenMismatchException on emended Iframe form on Chrome?

Tags: php, laravel, google-chrome, cookies, csrf

I have Laravel application on version 5.2 to create dynamic forms which can be emended to any web-page using Iframe, forms were working fine couple of months ago, but now not working on Chrome(latest version) due to following:

> this Set-Cookie didn't specify a "SameSite" attribute and was default to samesite=lax and was blocked because it came from the corss-site response which was not the response to a top-level navigtion. The Set-Cookie had to have been set with "SameSite=None" to enable cross-site requests.

Here is the Iframe with all attributes:

```
<iframe src="https://local.testproject.com/iframe/MSvnBNB9FT4H4m7kNi1OSJtdomsAxW3XnR6KZn1W9dStupbBLjYSfn7txRUNIDCa0UWCR4RbeiWJaMgy6JSDbZXzsFf8C6u32pUD5TiHPqJzxQiLwXXYm8SsUqHqhhoV" sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-top-navigation" style="width: 100%; height: 650px; border: none;"></iframe>
```

For further see attached screenshot: https://prnt.sc/u6el89

I have researched lot, but did find anything yet. even I customized the core file `vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Cookie.php`

Following is the customized `Cookie.php` file:

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of the Symfony package.
 *
 * (c) Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation;

/**
 * Represents a cookie.
 *
 * @author Johannes M. Schmitt <schmittjoh@gmail.com>
 */
class Cookie
{
    protected $name;
    protected $value;
    protected $domain;
    protected $expire;
    protected $path;
    protected $secure;
    protected $httpOnly;
    protected $sameSite;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param string                        $name     The name of the cookie
     * @param string                        $value    The value of the cookie
     * @param int|string|\DateTimeInterface $expire   The time the cookie expires
     * @param string                        $path     The path on the server in which the cookie will be available on
     * @param string                        $domain   The domain that the cookie is available to
     * @param bool                          $secure   Whether the cookie should only be transmitted over a secure HTTPS connection from the client
     * @param bool                          $httpOnly Whether the cookie will be made accessible only through the HTTP protocol
     *
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function __construct($name, $value = null, $expire = 0, $path = '/', $domain = null, $secure = false, $httpOnly = true, $sameSite='None')
    {
        // from PHP source code
        if (preg_match("/[=,; \t\r\n\013\014]/", $name)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('The cookie name "%s" contains invalid characters.', $name));
        }

        if (empty($name)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('The cookie name cannot be empty.');
        }

        // convert expiration time to a Unix timestamp
        if ($expire instanceof \DateTimeInterface) {
            $expire = $expire->format('U');
        } elseif (!is_numeric($expire)) {
            $expire = strtotime($expire);

            if (false === $expire || -1 === $expire) {
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException('The cookie expiration time is not valid.');
            }
        }

        $this->name = $name;
        $this->value = $value;
        $this->domain = $domain;
        $this->expire = $expire;
        $this->path = empty($path) ? '/' : $path;
        $this->secure = (bool) $secure;
        $this->httpOnly = (bool) $httpOnly;
        $this->sameSite = $sameSite;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the cookie as a string.
     *
     * @return string The cookie
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        $str = urlencode($this->getName()).'=';

        if ('' === (string) $this->getValue()) {
            $str .= 'deleted; expires='.gmdate('D, d-M-Y H:i:s T', time() - 31536001);
        } else {
            $str .= urlencode($this->getValue());

            if ($this->getExpiresTime() !== 0) {
                $str .= '; expires='.gmdate('D, d-M-Y H:i:s T', $this->getExpiresTime());
            }
        }

        if ($this->path) {
            $str .= '; path='.$this->path;
        }
        
        if ($this->sameSite) {
            $str .= '; SameSite='.$this->sameSite();
        }

        if ($this->getDomain()) {
            $str .= '; domain='.$this->getDomain();
        }

        if (true === $this->isSecure()) {
            $str .= '; secure';
        }

        if (true === $this->isHttpOnly()) {
            $str .= '; httponly';
        }

        return $str;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the name of the cookie.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the cookie.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getValue()
    {
        return $this->value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the domain that the cookie is available to.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDomain()
    {
        return $this->domain;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the time the cookie expires.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getExpiresTime()
    {
        return $this->expire;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the path on the server in which the cookie will be available on.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPath()
    {
        return $this->path;
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether the cookie should only be transmitted over a secure HTTPS connection from the client.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isSecure()
    {
        return $this->secure;
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether the cookie will be made accessible only through the HTTP protocol.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isHttpOnly()
    {
        return $this->httpOnly;
    }

    /**
     * Whether this cookie is about to be cleared.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isCleared()
    {
        return $this->expire < time();
    }
    
    /**
     * Whether this cookie same site.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function sameSite()
    {
        return $this->sameSite;
    }
}
```

Also have added in parameter `config/session.php`:

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Same-Site Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option determines how your cookies behave when cross-site requests
    | take place, and can be used to mitigate CSRF attacks. By default, we
    | do not enable this as other CSRF protection services are in place.
    |
    | Supported: "lax", "strict", "none"
    |
    */

    'same_site' => 'None'
```

After that I modified the `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php` and added new parameter `same_site` in following method:

```
protected function addCookieToResponse($request, $response)
    {
        $config = config('session');

        $response->headers->setCookie(
            new Cookie(
                'XSRF-TOKEN', $request->session()->token(), time() + 60 * $config['lifetime'],
                $config['path'], $config['domain'], $config['secure'], false, $config['same_site']
            )
        );

        return $response;
    }
```

Still no luck! I know that modifying core is the not good practice, but I just wanted to make this thing work. please guide how can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `same_site` attribute was added to laravel in version 5.5:
[image]

To use it you must update your laravel app or use simple trick which involves editing `path` attribute in `config/session.php` to:

```php
'path' => '/;samesite=none',
```

And there you go!

Comment: I also tried this ```'path' => '/;samesite=none',```, but it did not worked.

Comment: What's your PHP version?

Comment: php version 7.3

Comment: Since php 7.3 'path' value is escaped, so your only solution is probably to upgrade your laravel app.